# java binary search tree find parent

Tags: java, parent-child, binary-search-tree

im working on a method to find the parent of anode. I start at the root and then go down the leaves as long as they are not null and not the node of the child.

below is my code, its a little messy because im trying to test it to see whats going wrong.

The tree that i have is

```
        10
      /    \
     2     20
      \   / \
       3 18 22
            /
           21
```

The x that is being passed in is 20 so 10 is the parent but when i run it 22 comes out as the parent. the while loop seems to not be working, is it the way ive written it?

```
public Node<E> findParent(E x)
{
Node<E> node = root;

System.out.println("node is " + node.getData() + " before the search");
System.out.println("The value of x is " + x);
System.out.println("The value of node.getRight is " + node.getRight().getData());
boolean test = !node.getRight().getData().equals(x);
System.out.println("does nodes data equal x " + test);
while(((node!=null) && (node.getLeft()!=null) && (!node.getLeft().getData().equals(x))) || 
 ((node != null) && (node.getRight()!=null) && (!node.getRight().getData().equals(x))))
{ System.out.println("why didnt it stop");
    if(x.compareTo(node.getData()) < 0)
    {
        node = node.getLeft();
    }
    else
    {
        node = node.getRight();
    }
}
 System.out.println("node is " + node.getData() + " after the search");
return node;
}
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or print statements) to trace the behaviour of your code, and identify the point at which its behaviour diverges from what you expected.

Comment: i have traced the behavior of my code. that is what all the print statements are for, i track what the value of node is at the start and at the end. and ive made sure that when im at 10 then 20 is the right child. I do not think i should ahve been marked down for this question, ive spent alot of time running through it to see if im doing it right

Comment: You should continue with this debugging approach.  At some point, the value of some variable will not be what you expected.  At that point, you will have found your bug.

Comment: and i know when it diverges from what i expect, its when it enters the while loop so i suspect that something is wrong with the while loops conditions

Comment: Ok, in that case you should determine the value of each component of the while condition.  Is each one what you expected/intended?

Comment: yes i tested each condition and they are all what i expected. below is the printouts of my test. as you can see the node is 10 so it shouldnt go into the while because 10 is 20's parent.node is 10 before the search
The value of x is 20
The value of node.getRight is 20
does nodes data equal x false
is node null? false
is node.getleft null? false
is node.getright null? false
 does node.getleft equal x? false
does node.getright equal x? true

Comment: In that case, you have made a logical error when designing your code.  If the code is misbehaving, then at least one of those conditions is incorrect.  The task is to figure out which one ;)

Comment: i know that i have to find out whats wrong, thats why im asking fo rhelp

Comment: I can't give you any more help without actually doing your debugging for you.  You need to figure out (maybe with pencil and paper, step-by-step) what the logic should be, and compare this to what you've written in your code.

Answer (score 6):

I would do it differently: do the recursion in an auxiliary method that is passed the current node and the current parent node. It makes everything much simpler:

```
public Node<E> findParent(E x) {
    return findParent(x, root, null);
}

public Node<E> findParent(E x, Node<E> node, Node<E> parent)
{
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!node.getData().equals(x)) {
        parent = findParent(x, node.getLeft(), node);
        if (parent == null) {
            parent = findParent(x, node.getRight(), node);
        }
    }
    return parent;
}
```

Comment: so parent == null determines if you go left or right in the tree?

Comment: @alexthefourth - After finding that `x` is node at `node`, this always goes left first. If `parent == null` after that, then `x` was not in the left subtree and you need to search the right subtree.

Comment: Er, that was supposed to be "After finding that `x` is **not** at `node`. ..."

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void myparent(int data, Node R) 
{
    if( (R.left!=null && R.left.data == data) || (R.right!=null) &&(R.right.data == data) )
    {
        pRoot = R;
        return;
    }
    if (R.data <= data)
        myparent(data, R.right);
    else
        myparent(data, R.left);
}
```

Where "Data" is the value of the node whose parent we need to search and R is the root node of  the BST.
pRoot is my global data structure as I used it at other operations on BST.

Answer (score -1):

This is just pseudocode. when you are at a node `x`, check for the key (of child whose parent is to be found) in the left and right node. If they match, then you are already at the parent. If not then it's safe to move in the direction of the element and perform again.

Note that we check in the next level before proceeding.

```
while(node!=null){

  if(node.left==key || node.right==key) return node;

  if(key<node.data) node=node.left;

  else node=node.right;

  return null;
}
```